# Why does a delay change the number of running QThreads?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, sleep

The following example program uses `QThread` instances to run jobs from a queue.

```
from queue import Queue
from sys import argv
from threading import Lock
from time import sleep
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, QThread, pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication

class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, number):
        super().__init__()
        self.number = number

    @pyqtSlot()
    def work(self):
        while True:
            job = queue.get()
            if job is None:
                self.finished.emit()
                return
            with lock:
                print('worker={} job={}'.format(self.number, job))
            sleep(1)

app = QApplication(argv)
lock = Lock()
queue = Queue()
threads = []
nthreads = 4
for ithread in range(nthreads):
    thread = QThread()
    worker = Worker(ithread + 1)
    worker.moveToThread(thread)
    thread.started.connect(worker.work)
    worker.finished.connect(thread.quit)
    thread.start()
    threads += [thread]
    #-----------
    sleep(1e-10)
    #-----------

for ijob in range(10):
    queue.put(ijob + 1)

for _ in range(nthreads):
    queue.put(None)
for thread in threads:
    thread.wait()
```

With the `sleep` call (see marked line), all threads are running as expected. Output:

```
worker=1 job=1
worker=2 job=2
worker=3 job=3
worker=4 job=4
[…]
```

Without the call, an arbitrary number of threads is running. Output:

```
worker=4 job=1
worker=4 job=2
worker=4 job=3
worker=4 job=4
[…]
```

I have tested this with PyQt 5 in Python 3.6.2, other versions, a variable sleep duration, different orders of statements, and a running event loop.

Why does the `sleep` call change the number of running threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three worker objects are prone to garbage-collection, whilst the fourth one is left as a global variable. The `sleep` allows just enough time for each thread to call the `work` method of its associated worker, and this will keep them all alive (since the methods run blocking while-loops). Without the `sleep`, the first three workers will be immediately garbage-collected, leaving only the fourth to process the queue. If the workers are kept in a list (in the same way as the threads), you should see *all* of them being utilised (with or without the sleep).

To prove that this is what is going on, you can add this to the `Worker` class:

```
class Worker(QObject)
    ...

    def __del__(self):
        print('deleted:', self.number)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That means `connect` does not increase the reference count (verified with `sys.getrefcount`) and Python’s garbage collection can be faster than the already started QThread.